# Magento 2 : customer attribute not saved

Tags: magento2, php

I created a custom customer attribute with the following script :

```
$customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
$usedInForms = ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create'];

$customerSetup->addAttribute(
  \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
  'company_legal_form',
  [
    'type'         => 'varchar',
    'label'        => 'Company Legal Form',
    'input'        => 'text',
    'required'     => false,
    'visible'      => true,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'position'     => 92,
    'system'       => 0,
  ]
);
$customerAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'company_legal_form');
$customerAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', $usedInForms);
$customerAttribute->save();
```

I am able to see the new field on the customer registration form but my value is not saved ?
I clear all caches but nothing is working...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Are you getting the value on post method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below Code:

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\Context;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory;

class CustomerSetup extends EavSetup {

    protected $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        Context $context,
        CacheInterface $cache,
        CollectionFactory $attrGroupCollectionFactory,
        Config $eavConfig
        ) {
        $this -> eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        parent :: __construct($setup, $context, $cache, $attrGroupCollectionFactory);


} 

    public function installAttributes($customerSetup) {
        $this -> installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup);
        $this -> installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup);
    } 



public function installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup) {


        $customerSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'company_legal_form',
            [
            'label' => 'Company Legal Form',
            'system' => 0,
            'position' => 100,
            'sort_order' =>100,
            'visible' =>  true,
            'note' => '',


                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'input' => 'text',

            ]
            );

        $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer', 'company_legal_form')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',0)->setData('default_value','')->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout']) -> save();


    } 

    public function installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup) {

    } 

    public function getEavConfig() {
        return $this -> eavConfig;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to be working, what I was doing wrong ?

Comment: Might be in $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer', 'company_legal_form')->setData();...........
Please Click on Right mark if it's working... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create Custom Customer Attribute just using below code-

```
<?php

namespace Vishal\NewCustomerAttribute\Setup;    

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface 
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Config
     */
    private $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Installs data for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $setup->startSetup();

        $attributeCode = 'account_id';
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, 'account_id', [
            'label' => 'Account Id',
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => 1,
            'system' => 0,
            'position' => 100,
            'input' => 'text'
        ]);

        $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
            null,
            $attributeCode);

        $amountId = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);
        $amountId->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);
        $amountId->getResource()->save($amountId);

        $attributeCode = 'amount_spend';

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode, [
            'label' => 'Amount Spent',
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => 1,
            'system' => 0,
            'position' => 110
        ]);

        $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
            null,
            $attributeCode);

        $amountSpend = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);
        $amountSpend->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);
        $amountSpend->getResource()->save($amountSpend);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

After **Upgrade** and **Deploy** you can see these fields in your Admin (Customer Edit Section).

For showing this customer attribute on the registration page, we need to do following things :

We will add our phtml files to ‘form.additional.info’ reference name using `Vishal/Customerattr/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml`

```
<page
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_attributes" template="Vishal_NewCustomerAttribute::extra_field.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Explaination : we’re not overriding the entire `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml` file. Instead we used container name form.additional.info as reference and adding a new block to it. **‘form.additional.info’** is being called in register.phtml using this code `<?php getChildHtml(‘form_additional_info’); ?>`

So by above xml we can simply add new attribute fields with editing register.phtml of core or without overriding it and `<?php getChildHtml(‘form_additional_info’); ?>` automatically read content of **‘form.additional.info’** child block.

Now, in the **extra_field.phtml** file, we will write the code to show the additional textbox:

```
<fieldset class="fieldset create account">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend><br>

    <div class="field custom_account_id">

        <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Account Id')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="account_id" id="account_id" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('My Custom Attribute') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:false}" autocomplete="off">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="field custom_amount_spend required">

        <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Amount Spend')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="amount_spend" id="amount_spend" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('My Custom Attribute') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off">
        </div>

    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Data gets stored into the database in `customer_entity_varchar` table. This table contains following field:

**value_id:** It is just the auto-increament primary key for the table.

**attribute_id:** The attribute’s id which we had previosuly seen in eav_attribute table.

**entity_id:** It will contain the customer id.

**value:** It contains the value for the attribute which was filled while registration.

that's it. it will show like the attached screenshot. Hope it's Help !!

**ADMIN AREA--**

[image]

**FRONTEND--**

[image]